# Make my wordpress blog remember my login "forever"

Tags: login

Is there a way to make Wordpress' "Remember Me" login checkbox work for a really long time, like a year? Currently I think it only works for a few days or a week max, usually I am not remembered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I think I'll wait for such a plugin

Save this code in a file named `set-cookie-expire.php` and upload it your plugins folder.

The plugin will give you the ability to set a time (in days) that cookies expire within the WordPress Settings admin.

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: Set Cookie Expire
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/11991/1685
 * Version:     0.1
 * Description: Set the expire time for cookies in your <a href="options-general.php">general settings</a>.
 * Author:      WordPress Development Stack Exchange
 * Author URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/11991/1685
 */

/**
 * Set our user-specified expire times.
 *
 * @param  int $default
 * @param  int $user_id
 * @param  bool $remember
 * @return int
 */
function wpse_11979_set_cookie_expire( $default, $user_id, $remember ) {
    $days = get_option( $remember ? 'remember_cookie_expire' : 'normal_cookie_expire' );

    if ( $days === false )
        $days = $remember ? 14 : 2;
    else
        $days = ( int ) $days;

    return $days * DAY_IN_SECONDS;
}

add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'wpse_11979_set_cookie_expire', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Register settings.
 */
function wpse_11979_set_cookie_expire_settings() {
    $settings = array(
        'normal_cookie_expire'   => 'Normal Cookie Expire',
        'remember_cookie_expire' => 'Remember Cookie Expire',
    );

    foreach ( $settings as $id => $label ) {
        add_settings_field(
            $id,
            $label,
            'wpse_11979_set_cookie_expire_field',
            'general',
            'default',
            array(
                'label_for' => $id,
            )
        );

        register_setting( 'general', $id, 'absint' );
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_11979_set_cookie_expire_settings' );

/**
 * Render settings field.
 *
 * @param array $args
 */
function wpse_11979_set_cookie_expire_field( $args ) {
    $id = $args['label_for'];

    printf(
        '<input id="%2$s" type="text" name="%2$s" value="%1$d" class="small-text" /> days',
        ( int ) get_option( $id, $id === 'normal_cookie_expire' ? 2 : 14 ),
        $id
    );
}
```

Comment: Awesome! +10 for writing a plugin as an answer.

Comment: Sorry to answer here, but "you must have 50 points to comment...". @TheDeadMedic, plugin not works with current Wordpress version.

Comment: @EduardDimitroff note that you got automated flags against your account for doing that, be very careful as a 1 rep user you could be auto-flagged as a spammer. You can get 50 reputation easily by writing a good answer or a question that gets upvoted. Once you have 100 rep on any stack exchange site you get 100 on every other site ( including stackoverflow ).

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress versions great than 2.4 store two cookies that set to expire in two weeks according to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies). According to this [blog post](http://www.planetmike.com/2008/06/30/how-to-make-the-wordpress-login-cookie-last-longer-than-two-weeks/) (linked in the Codex), you can edit the `wp_set_auth_cookie` function in the `pluggable.php` file in the `wp-includes` folder of Wordpress. The exact line will depend on which version of Wordpress you are using.

What is probably better is to write or use a plug-in to replace the [wp_set_auth_cookie](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie) function instead. If you edit the Wordpress core files, they will be replaced if you use the auto-updater or do a manual installation of Wordpress and copy the files without preserving whatever changes you made.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I think I'll wait for such a plugin, not too thrilled to get into WP code right now.

Comment: Good choice. You shouldn't ever edit core files, whether you're thrilled about it or not. ;)